# Сравнение элементов массива с учетом индекса (PHP)

Tags: массивы, php

В общем, нужно сравнить и подсчитать кол-во одинаковых элементов двух массивов с учетом их расположения (индекса).

```
echo $pix_array[0]."<br>";
echo $mem_array[0]."<br>";

$result_array = array_intersect_assoc($mem_array, $pix_array);
print_r($result_array);
echo  "<br>W=".count($result_array);
```

Получаю вывод:

```
0.89803921568627
0.89803921568627
Array ( )
W=0
```

**Пишет, что нет похожих, хотя одинаковых элементов должно быть 60к.**

Собственно, первый массив получаю из файла:

```
$mem_array = file("brain.log");
```

Второй, путем заполнения в цикле:

```
$i = 0;
for($y=0; $y<200; $y++){ 
for($x=0; $x < 300; $x++){
$rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y) / 16777215;
$pix_array[$i] = $rgb;
$i++;
}}
```

Если сравнивать как:

```
$result_array = array_intersect_assoc(array("0.89803921568627", "0.90196078431373"), array("0.89803921568627", "0.90196078431373"));
```

То работает.

В чем может быть косяк?

Comment: выделите проблему, brainlog оставьте себе

Comment: http://ideone.com/zepYTz array_intersect_assoc работает нормально, сделайте trim/rtrim на строки получаемые из файла.

Comment: Спс, работает

Comment: http://ideone.com/zepYTz